# Puppet: how many times an exec block with creates run?

Tags: puppet

I have the below two `exec` resources and would like the `exec` resource `run the script` to run whenever the file `/var/lib/my-file` is not present. I'm wondering what would happen if the file never gets created. Would the `exec` resource `check if file exists` run forever in a loop until it gets created?

```
exec { 'run the script':
  command     => "python my-script.py",
  path        => '/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin',
  timeout     => 900,
  subscribe   => File["my-settings.yaml"],
  refreshonly => true,
} 

exec { 'check if file exists':
  command => 'true',
  path    => '/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin',
  creates => '/var/lib/my-file',
  notify  => Exec['run the script']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resource is only applied once per catalog application, which occurs once per catalog compilation per node. You can verify this for yourself by trying it out.

If the Python script fails to create the file, the resource would simply be applied again during the next catalog application. Otherwise, idempotence prevails and the resource is not applied because the file already exists.

Additionally, you should simplify your resources into:

```
exec { 'run the script':
  command     => 'python my-script.py',
  path        => '/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin',
  timeout     => 900,
  creates     => '/var/lib/my-file',
  subscribe   => File["my-settings.yaml"],
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

This is functionally the same as what you have in your question and is more efficient and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying it. The exec blocks also need to listen on any changes to the file "my-settings.yaml". Wondering if the removal of it is intentional.

Comment: @Hem Oh I missed that part. It should be re-added indeed. Editing answer. Putting two idempotence attributes into the `exec` resource is also fine by the way.